# How to correlate SUPL WcdmaCellInformation with MLS cell id

Tags: supl, supl-2.0

I'm trying to understand how to interpret data from a SUPL* messages containing a wcdmaCellInformation. I've captured the data from my handset, the relevant section looks like this:

```
    locationId: LocationId ::= {
        cellInfo: WcdmaCellInformation ::= {
            refMCC: 204
            refMNC: 8
            refUC: 4247339
        }
        status: 1
    }
```

I'm trying to look up this cell information in the mozilla location services data. I've downloaded the data from https://location.services.mozilla.com/downloads and extracted it.

I can easily find matches for the refMCC (mobile country code, 204 is Netherlands) and refMNC (8 is KPN), but I'm stuck on finding the right cell in the MLS data.

If I grep for the refUC I only find a few lines from different countries, like this:

```
GSM,724,6,2044,10333,,30.5240236,50.4392184,0,1,1,1424733937,1634217543,
LTE,250,1,11264,84247339,11,47.8775878,56.6526018,449,19,1,1462207606,1630887268,
```

Is there some kind of step I'm missing to be able to do a lookup from the refUC to the cell id?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for some reason, there's an off-by-one either on the side of Mozilla Location Services, or on the side of the SET doing the request.

Subtracting one from the `refUC` seems to consistently find cellular base stations that are very close to where I actually am. Maybe MLS stores the IDs zero-based, while the SET uses 1-based IDs.